# ASP.NET MVC 2 using Visual Studio 2010. Changing the Roles Manager through web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have implemented my own custom Role manager object. When I run my web app using the visual studio version of IIS, it works fine. I can see the username and I can drill into my Role Manager class and see what it's doing. When I debug the app using IIS 7, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is blank and it does not use my Role Manager class when determining what roles my user has. I've checked that all my dlls are in the bin directory.

I'm guessing that the problem is on IIS 7. What do I need to configure on IIS 7 to make this work and to make it use my Role manager?

Here is a snippet of the web.config that sets the role manager.

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="HyperionRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="HyperionRoleProvider" type="Census.BUD.Common.HyperionRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

From:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/528/how-to-use-the-sample-read-only-xml-membership-and-role-providers-with-iis-70/

"These samples are excellent for use with IIS 7.0 for demonstration or test Web sites, but they don't work as-written with IIS 7.0 because of the way that IIS 7.0's security is designed. The original instructions allowed you to deploy the sample membership/role providers into the App_Code folder of your Web site, but IIS 7.0 requires that providers are registered in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) before they can be deployed. With that in mind, the following steps will walk you through compiling and deploying the read-only XML providers on a development system."

Make sure your assembly is in the GAC

Comment: The problem I have now is that I'm using windows 2008 and I compile ok based on the article, but I don't see my assemblies in the c:\windows\assembly directory. Does Windows Server 2008 do something else with the assemblies?

Comment: You need to take the assembly that your role provider is in (I would separate out that provider code into a separate library) and then drag and drop it into c:\windows\assembly (click start, run, then enter in c:\windows\assembly as the easiest way). In order to put it into the GAC you also have to make sure your library is signed as well which you can do on your project properties.

Comment: Then you can at least test it easily - its possible your gacutil command is failing (although you should see that when you compile your project)